# Автоматическое появление модального окна

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть два модальных окна. Первое появляется при нажатии на ссылку. А второе должно появляться при загрузке страницы. Каким образом это можно сделать? Пробовал имитировать нажатие на ссылку при помощи js при заходе на сайт, только окошко почему-то не вылазит.

```css
.overlay {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    position: fixed;
    cursor: default;
}
.overlay:target {
    display: block;
}
.popup {
    top: -100%;
    right: 0;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 99999;
    margin: 0;
    width: 85%;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 600px;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #383838;
    background: #fefefe;       
    border-radius: 4px;
    font: 14px/18px 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);    
    box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.overlay:target + .popup {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    top: 25%;
}

.close {
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #FFA500;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    text-align: center;        
    font-weight: bold; 
}

.close:before {
    color: black;
    content: "X";
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);             
}

.close:hover {
    background-color: #FFD33B;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="prizewin"></a>       
        <div class="popup">
            Text
            <a class="close" title="Закрыть" href="#close"></a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Реализация не сложная** , окно откроется через 5 сек

```js
var delay = 5000;
setTimeout("document.getElementById('modal1').style.display='block'", delay);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.modal1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightgreen;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px #ccc;
  display: none;
}

.modal1 p {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: rgba(67, 139, 76, 1);
  color: #fbfbfb;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.close {
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 131, 119, 0.9);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.close:before {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  content: "X";
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: rgba(252, 20, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="modal1" class="modal1">
    <p> появится при загрузке страницы</p>
    <button class="close" title="Закрыть" onclick="document.getElementById('modal1').style.display='none';"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```